# Problem: figure caption's automatic change in ieeeconf

Tags: captions, ieeeconf

Disclaimer: *I know that `IEEEconf` is replaced with `ieeeconf`(http://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/files/ieeeconf.zip), but my target conference template is still the latter, so I must use the latter, as some of you may suggest using the former. (Furthermore, applying any change such as removing `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` will disturb the template's output formation.)*

The template is supposed to set the caption's font size to 8 pt, automatically. But as you can check following MWE, the target font size will be compiled just like the main text.

What do I do wrong?!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
%\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\title{\LARGE \bf
XXXXXXXXX
}

\author{Y$^{1}$ and X$^{2}$
%\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}
\thanks{$^{1}$Y is with 
        University of Y, 
        {\tt\small y@y.com}}
\thanks{$^{2}$X with the Department of Electrical Engineering, Hell,
        HELL
        {\tt\small x@daemon.hell}}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

This paper considers ...

\end{abstract}


\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{figure}[]
      \centering
%      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{adj_config}
      \caption{Inductance of oscillation winding on amorphous magnetic core versus DC bias magnetic  field}
      \label{figurelabel}
   \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If your target is the latter, why must you use the former?

Comment: @cfr: My wrong assertion. I must use `ieeeconf`. Updated

Comment: Don't use two-letter font switches in LaTeX, by the way. Unless you are using 2.09 which is 20+ years obsolete.

Comment: Did they tell you to use maths for superscripts in text and appearance markup for stuff like the title? You shouldn't, but if they make you, they make you.

Comment: @cfr: Yes. Those superscripts are some part of the requirements.

Comment: They should use the text version. Oh well. But your question still seems confusing. If `iee...` replaced `IEE...`, why should anybody suggest you use the old one?

Comment: @cfr: `\bf` is among the things they're happy to see in submitted `*.tex` files, as well!

Comment: @I don't know, why. Maybe they (IROS) like the old days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange issue is not really due to disadvantages of `ieeeconf`, as this could also occurred for both `IEEEconf` and `ieeetran`, too. (As I checked)

The problem is seemingly stems from some sort of conflict between template's settings and `subconfig` package. As I did add following options to it, the size of the captions appropriately switched to what it must be: `8 point`:

```
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
```

[image]